# How to find the next group value using Big query SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I have a table with following values.

```
Order Id    Order_start_date
O1          9/10/2022
O1          9/10/2022
O1          9/12/2023
O1          9/12/2023
O1          9/14/2023
O1          9/14/2023
```

I want to get next_order_start_dt as which is next group start date.
So Result I am expecting as

```
Order_id    Order_start_date    Next_Order_start_date
O1          9/10/2022           9/12/2023
O1          9/10/2022           9/12/2023
O1          9/12/2023           9/14/2023
O1          9/12/2023           9/14/2023
O1          9/14/2023           Null
O1          9/14/2023           Null
```

Here is my Table SQL

```
WITH  ORDER_DETAIL AS 
(
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-09-10') AS ORDER_START_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-09-10') AS ORDER_START_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-09-12')  AS ORDER_START_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-09-12')  AS ORDER_START_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-09-14') AS ORDER_START_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-09-14') AS ORDER_START_DT
)
SELECT ORD_ID, ORDER_START_DT
FROM ORDER_DETAIL
```

How will I get the Next_order_start_dt using Big query SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider below.

```sql
SELECT ORD_ID, ORDER_START_DT,
       FIRST_VALUE(ORDER_START_DT) OVER w1 AS Next_Order_start_date
  FROM (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER w0 AS rnk
      FROM ORDER_DETAIL
    WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY ORD_ID ORDER BY ORDER_START_DT)
  ) WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY ORD_ID ORDER BY rnk RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING);
```

- [RANGE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls#def_window_frame) window frame

**Query result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the window function `dense_rank()` to return rank for each record then using `self left join` by the condition `s.rn = t.rn+1` to get the next value for each row

```
WITH  ORDER_DETAIL AS 
(
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-09-10') AS ORDER_START_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-09-10') AS ORDER_START_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-09-12')  AS ORDER_START_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-09-12')  AS ORDER_START_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-09-14') AS ORDER_START_DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'O1' AS ORD_ID , DATE('2022-09-14') AS ORDER_START_DT
),
cte as (
    select *, dense_rank() over (order by ORDER_START_DT) as rn
    from ORDER_DETAIL
)
select t.ORD_ID as Order_id, t.ORDER_START_DT as Order_start_date, s.ORDER_START_DT as Next_Order_start_date
from cte t
left join (
    select DISTINCT ORDER_START_DT, rn
    from cte
) as s on s.rn = t.rn+1
```